# Google Places API: store Places in DB

Tags: database, google-places-api

I am building a web app where all the users belong to some type of places, lets say "bank". Each user belongs to only 1 bank but 1 bank can have more then one user.

I need to display their bank name and location in user profile and to be able to search by bank names inside specific city. So I need to connect users and banks somehow.

Is it safe to use the Place ID for that for each bank in terms of app scalability and life-cycle?

The [manual](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) says:

> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section
>   10.5.d of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely.

So Google says I can but is it the best practise? Do I need to store a full address additionally to be safe in case Google will deprecate these IDs in future?

Let's say I can get the bank Place ID with the help of [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) during the user registration. Then I need to save it to DB to be able to display it later and search by bank.

The DB Structure could be:
[image]

Or Just

[image]

But I think the 1st way it better with unique place_id column?

Answer (score 3):

As Google says, you may store PlaceID, but they also tell you that it is a good practice to "refresh" these stored PlaceIDs each 100 days, they do not assure you that your stored PlaceID will be for the same place that you stored.

https://developers.google.com/places/place-id